# How can i input this data using scanf or anything in c?

Tags: c, input

i want to input this data. line 1 to variabel float, line 2 and 3 to 2 variabel array of char. but line 2 and 3 can just bellow 16 character

```
100.0
t g r m n c p f
t k n r m c p o
```

i try to using this but there is many bug

```c
scanf("%lf", &identic);
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    scanf("%c", &compK[i]);
    if(compK[i] == ' '){
        i--;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    scanf("%c", &compL[i]);
    if(compL[i] == ' '){
        i--;
    }
}
```

i got headache for this problem

Comment: You almost always want to use `" %c"`, not `"%c"`.  That extra space makes a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

The format strings are a bit annoying but I would probably do it like this instead of a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = "100.0\n"
        "t g r m n c p f\n"
        "t k n r m c p o\n";
    double identic;
    char compK[8];
    char compL[8];
    int n = sscanf(s, "%lf\n"
        "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n"
        "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n",
        &identic,
        compK, compK+1, compK+2, compK+3, compK+4,compK+5, compK+6, compK+7,
        compL, compL+1, compL+2, compL+3, compL+4,compL+5, compL+6, compL+7
    );
    if(n != 17) {
        printf("cry %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%lf\n%.8s\n%.8s\n",
        identic,
        compK,
        compL
    );
}
```

You could also just read a line with `fgets()` and write a function parses the data(say, return next char, then skips optional space).